# Adding invoice to QuickBooks Harmony, getting "Business Validation Error" related to taxes?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

One of our clients is unable to export an invoice to QuickBooks Online Harmony using the new v3 REST API. The error they get is "Business Validation Error: One or more transaction lines do not have a tax code associated with it. Please assign a tax code for those lines."

An example request and response are shown below.

I'm wondering:

- Is this related to a sales tax setting that our client has set?
- Which setting? (I'd like to be able to reproduce the setup on a test company)
- Do we need to send additional data in the invoice add request to accommodate that setting?

For what it's worth, the client is based in Canada. Testing an invoice export with similar data for a non-Canadian company works fine. Thanks for the help.

EXAMPLE REQUEST:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <TxnDate>2014-03-12</TxnDate>
    <PrivateNote>Some private note.</PrivateNote>
    <Line>
        <Description>My Description</Description>
        <Amount>3333.33</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <SalesItemLineDetail>
            <ItemRef name="My Description">3</ItemRef>
            <ClassRef name="3">3333</ClassRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <CustomerRef name="My Customer Name">33</CustomerRef>
    <ClassRef name="3">3333</ClassRef>
</Invoice>
```

EXAMPLE RESPONSE:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-13T11:47:58.052-07:00">
    <Fault type="ValidationFault">
        <Error code="6000" element="">
            <Message>A business validation error has occurred while processing your request</Message>
            <Detail>Business Validation Error: One or more transaction lines do not have a tax code associated with it. Please assign a tax code for those lines.</Detail>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have already enabled sales tax settings. The next thing you can do is create the invoice in the UI and then load it through the API as Matt suggested. Assign some tax to the invoice and Read it using API explorer.
THis will give you an idea as to what is expected in the lines. This will definitely help you out with the correct tags you need to set.

Alternately refer to the docs with example request here-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting#/complex-data-types

Global tax model-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/global_tax_model

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a few questions about this: (1)Does this behave differently for US vs. Canada? When I setup sales tax for a US test company, tax codes are not required when adding an invoice and I don't get the error. When my Canadian customer tries to add an invoice, they get the error. (2)Is it possible to configure a US company so that it would experience this behavior? Without a Canadian test company, I don't know how I would test my fix. (3)Is fixing the issue just a matter of passing TaxCodeRef = NON|TAX ? If I specify TAX, do I actually need to indicate which TAX applies?

Comment: edited my answer above. There is a very good doc on this. Please read through it for the diff in behavior for US vs Global tax model.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that - is there a way to specify that an invoice line item just use whichever tax defaults have been defined for that product/service, or specify to specify *no* taxes for the line item? ... Or is it always required that invoice line items specify at least one tax to apply?

Comment: After much testing with a QBO Canada trial company (no way to repro the original issue, otherwise), it looks like I always have to specify a TaxCode, even if QBO already has a default tax code assigned in the Products/Services list. Leaving TaxCode empty, set to null, or otherwise leaving it out just produces the same error. Thanks for sending a link to the Global tax model article, nimisha shrivastava. It's not great news (since it makes it a higher barrier to entry for sharing data with QBO Canada), but it looks like the only way past the validation error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. That's true. You need to have a tax code with zero tax rate value and assign it to each line if you don't want any tax associated with it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have sales tax enabled in QBO, then all line items in invoice need to have a [TaxCodeRef](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice#SalesItemLineDetail), and there needs to be a [TxnTaxDetail](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#TxnTaxDetail) object on the invoice itself. You should be able to get the numerical values that need to go into these values from the [TaxCode](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/taxcode)/[TaxRate](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/taxrate) endpoints.

Your best bet is to create the invoice in the UI and then load it through the API so you can see what it's meant to look like.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you wrote "have sales tax enabled" what did you mean, specifically? Here's what I'm setting up for a test company in QBO, in the Edit Sales Tax Settings popup: "Do you charge sales tax?" = "yes"; default sales tax set, "Mark all new $$customers$$ taxable" checked; "Mark all new products and services taxable" checked;

That doesn't put my test company into a state where I get the error I posted about. Is there additional sales tax setup that I need to do?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that one. I'm afraid we use QBO in the UK where Sales Tax (VAT) is either on or off.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Is VAT the only tax that you have? I've only setup the one tax, so perhaps I need to setup multiple taxes to see the "required TxnTaxDetail" behavior

Comment: Yes it is the only tax we have. I'd say we consider ourselves fortunate but the VAT model in QBO has still proved quite challenging for us!

Comment: Confirmed that multiple taxes, multi-part taxes don't matter. I still can't make it fail. It has to be a US QBO vs. non-US QBO thing. Last question: are you using the new v3 API, and connecting to the new Harmony QBO UI?

Comment: Yes we are on V3 and Harmony. Not sure if it makes a difference but we're using the .NET V3 SDK as well (which formulates the XML for us)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well and while it took me forever to figure it out, the answer is simple.

If tax is enabled for the company, every line *must* have a tax code, *whether there is tax applied or not*. That means that there should be a tax code in the system for "no tax". (For Australia, this is called "OOS" or "Out Of Scope" - apparently which one you get depends on when you set up tax, so look for both!)

If there is $0 tax for a particular line, you must explicitly attach this no-tax tax code, and cannot leave it null.

Comment: I have got trouble in this section. My Lineitem code is used in both US and Canada. In Us there is no problem when Tax code passing as Null. But, Canada It throws the same error that Mentioned above. Then how to get rid of this. ?   Can you please give me the example that how we can set the default values for that?